# Wpf lines not displaying properly

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to display multiple UserControls that i designed in wpf but their lines are not showing correctly

theres an image to describe the problem:
[image]

heres the xaml code i used for drawing the lines:

```
<Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="20" X2="340" Y2="20" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="35" X2="340" Y2="35" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="50" X2="340" Y2="50" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="65" X2="340" Y2="65" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="80" X2="340" Y2="80" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="95" X2="340" Y2="95" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="110" X2="340" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>

    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="30" Y1="10" X2="30" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="99" Y1="10" X2="99" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="177" Y1="10" X2="177" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="256" Y1="10" X2="256" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="340" Y1="10" X2="340" Y2="110" Stroke="LightCyan" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
```

its a simple code and i cant find the problem here...

the weird thing is when im resizing the window it sometimes shows the line correcly.

Comment: Increase the `StrokeThickness`. It should be at least `0.5`.

Comment: oh, that was all. thanks mate!

Comment: Personally, I would get so annoyed with the little quirks of `Line` in SL/WPF I just started using `Rectangle` with `Height` or `Width` set to 1 with a `Fill` for making that sort of stuff. Makes things so much quicker to do IMO.